# How to implement variable arguments in F#

Tags: f#

I want to implement a F# function which may accept 1 or 2 arguments. I would like to use the function like this:

```
let foo = ...
foo "a"
foo "a" "b"
```

Both the arguments can be the same type. I read the pages about *match pattern*, *active pattern*, but cannot find one works for me.

Comment: It's a bad habit to answer, you don't really need it, but that's what comes to my mind. If your your arguments is a list of values of the same type, just make them a `list`. If one of them is optional (e.g. may have default value that can be omitted), make it optional: `foo(a, ?b)`. You may also consider DU, if your data can be represented this way. Otherwise, I would just use two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, you might also be able to do what you want via partial application and currying.  Like this:

```
let foo a b =
   a + b

let foo2 a =
   foo 1 a;;
```

Obviously you'd want to fix the first parameter in the call to foo within foo2 to whatever default you want.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is due to some of the underlying .Net features, but I think you have to use a class with overloaded methods - something like

```
 type t() =
     static member foo a = "one arg"
     static member foo (a,b) = "two args"
```

Comment: Note that the second has to be a tuple because otherwise `foo "a"` is ambiguous between calling the first overload and currying the second.

Answer (score 5):

On a type member, you can use optional params:

```
type Helper private () =
    static member foo (input1, ?input2) =
          let input2 = defaultArg input2 "b"
          input1, input2
```

To call this method:

```
Helper.foo("a")
Helper.foo("a", "b")
```

Is this what you're after?

You can't use optional params on a function though, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, here are a few more "almost solutions". They are not strictly what you wanted, but are worth knowing anyway.

Using a list (or an array) and pattern matching:

```
let f = function
    | [a, b] -> ...
    | [a] -> ...
    | [] -> failwith "too few arguments"
    | _ -> failwith "too many arguments"

f ["a"]
f ["a" ; "b"]
```

Problems: parameters are not named, not clear from function signature how many parameters it takes.

Using a record to pass all optional parameters:

```
type FParams = { a : string; b : string }
let fdefault = { a = "a" ; b = "b" }

let f (pars: FParams) = ...

f { fdefault with b = "c" }
```

Problem: a is also optional, which is not what you wanted. Can be useful though.